# rails 4 - Could not find generator rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

Im trying to install the **rspec framework** for TDD and BDD testing, and also the **autotest** gem for a continuos testing running at the same time the changes are done.

I have been following all kind of tutorials, some of them here in stack overflow and others out there in the web, but i couldnt reach a solution, when executing the

> rails generate rspec:install

it throws me an error **'Could not find generator rspec:install'**.

I attach the gem file here: [UPDATED]

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1' 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change what you have in your Gemfile to what is below and save

```
 group :development, :test do
   gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
 end
```

Then run bundle update and then bundle install

Comment: now im facing problems with the autotest, i execute 'gem install ZenTest' and then 'gem install autotest-rails' and when i execute the autotest command it throws me an exception `'.autotest:1:in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method ruby' for main:Object (NameError)'`, any solution?

Comment: what operating system are you making use of and can you paste here your Gemfile.

Comment: im using ubuntu 13.10 and i updated the complete Gemfile in the question

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Here's what did:

Try this command:

```
spring stop
```

then run again:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Answer (score 3):

in the gem file, instead of adding

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.1.0'
```

to your selected environment, add

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring stop` fixed it for me.

possibly related:

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/486

[Rails Spring breaking generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165506/rails-spring-breaking-generators)