# Rails Spring breaking generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm setting up my first Rails 4.1 app, which comes with Spring, their new preloader. When I try to install Devise using their generator (`$ rails generate devise:install`), the command line just hangs and nothing gets generated.

If I remove Spring from the gem file and try again, the Devise generator works.

Anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 34):

Check directories of some other projects that you were working on at that time, chances are that the generated files ended up there.

spring seems to get confused when you work with more than one rails app at a time. That's probably what caused your problem

spring runs as a server and keeps a rails environment loaded. I think what happens is that if you work with more than one project at a time then spring system seems to get confused and uses wrong environment.

I have had a situation where I was running `rails g ...` in one project and the files were getting generated in another project. What was crazy was that I kept renaming and moving that other folder, and still the generator kept putting the files in that folder. As if spring had latched on the the inode of that folder.

Try `DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails g devise:install`

or `ps aux |grep spring` and kill all the processes you see and then run `rails g devise:install`

We are taking out spring from the `Gemfile` for now while this broken behavior persists, and in the future use `rails new --skip-spring`

If you want to keep using spring, then try following these rules

- Use new shells for each new project
- Use a new directory name for each new project (If you do `rails new blog`, work on it, then `mv blog blog.old` and `rails new blog` again, it might not work.
- From time to time keep on killing all the spring servers, for safety's (and sanity's) sake.

Comment: I had only one project, but still the rails generator took a long long time - removing spring from gemfile fixed it. So, spring is the problem, but not necessarily due to multiple projects

Comment: Indeed Spring is definitely broken. Way to go Rails team and add a broken gem by default.

Comment: Instead of killing processes, `spring stop` should suffice.

Comment: Is there a way to turn Spring on again without restarting terminal?

Answer (score 8):

You can disable spring for any `$ rails` command by passing the environment variable `DISABLE_SPRING=1`.

```
$ DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails generate devise:install
```

Alternatively, you can try `$ spring stop` to spin down the spring processes. Running `$ rails generate` afterwards will spin up a new spring process, which might solve the temporary issue.

Comment: `DISABLE_SPRING=1` will stop rails from directing commands through Spring, but the Spring server still runs in the background. This might or might not be a problem for the OP. Running `spring stop` from the command prompt *does* stop the Spring server (in Rails 4.2.0, at least), and commenting it out of the Gemfile keeps it from starting again. (Unless you work on another project that still has it enabled.)

Answer (score 3):

There is same problem on rails 5.1.4 for responders gem

I listed solutions along with previous ones:

- **close terminal and open new one**
- **run command with** 
   `DISABLE_SPRING=1 bundle exec rails generate responders:install` 

  or export it as environment variable

  `export DISABLE_SPRING=1`
- **kill running spring process for your app** 
  `ps ax | grep spring | grep YOUR_APP_NAME | cut -f1 -d' ' | xargs kill`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but i think my experience might help someone...

rails 5.0.1

I was facing same issue after i messed up some devise generated files(i am new to rails and learning) and than i tried rails destroy devise model and i was stuck, tried many time and nothing worked.

Googled, got here, tried excluding spring gems, and it worked, again added spring gems, and devise was again stuck on everything.

**I just closed the terminal and opened new one, and it worked.**

Comment: Seems like I just faced the same issue with Devise and Spring when I tried to place a RegistrationsController inside a `devise` folder on controllers. I'm not going to confirm and write anything else because I'm still solving it.