# Ruby on Rails invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, utf-8

When I running command

```
rails generate mongoid:config
```

or

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

I am getting this error - `match: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)`
I tried those gems:

```
gem 'rack-utf8_sanitizer'
gem "handle_invalid_percent_encoding_requests"
gem 'utf8-cleaner'
```

They do not help!
I am using macbook OSX 10.9
How can I fix it? 
I am using ruby 2.1.2 and I make app by rails new myapp and I have not change anything yet in the code.

Comment: What Ruby version do you use? How did you name your application when using `rails new NAME`?

Comment: Post the stack trace if there is one. You may have a gem that's incompatible with the Ruby version you're using.

Comment: did you added any string with "**ñ**" or "**´**" in your controllers or models?

I have had that issue before, and fixed with adding `#encoding: utf-8` at the beggining of the file

Comment: #encoding: utf-8 - at the beginning of which file??????

Comment: That is why I asked first if you added a "ñ" or "´" in any model or controller, if you did, thats the file where you are going to add the #encoding if not, well, its something else...

btw.. what if you try to add it in your `config/application.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem! It was a gem 'spring' which automatically adds to Gemfile when you run: rails new myapp. To avoid this problem you need to run: rails new myapp --skip-spring
I found answer here: [Rails Spring breaking generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165506/rails-spring-breaking-generators)