# Spring error when creating a new model in Rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to create a new model in a Rails API-only app but I geta "cannot load such file" error message:

```
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': cannot load such file -- rails/generators/model/model/model_generator (LoadError)
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork': undefined method `reject!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've changed the ruby versions but that didn't work.

```
rails generate model Product title:string release_date:date release_time:time description:text price:decimal brand:string
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a known issue but you should be able to run one-off rails command without stopping spring by using this:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails generate model Product title:string release_date:date release_time:time description:text price:decimal brand:string
```

Or you can first stop spring by running `spring stop`

See answers here as well [Rails Spring breaking generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165506/rails-spring-breaking-generators)

Comment: @MaxRah glad this fixed your problem. and if so, perhaps consider marking this as accepted the answer.