# Could not find generator 'wice_grid:install'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, wice-grid

## Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 6.0.2.1

## Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
    activerecord (6.0.2.1)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
    activestorage (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capybara (3.29.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.11.3)
    font-awesome-sass (4.7.0)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    mysql2 (0.5.3)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (4.3.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.0.8)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.2.1)
      actioncable (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      actiontext (= 6.0.2.1)
      actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
      activejob (= 6.0.2.1)
      activemodel (= 6.0.2.1)
      activerecord (= 6.0.2.1)
      activestorage (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.2.1)
      actionpack (= 6.0.2.1)
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.6)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    tiny_tds (2.1.2)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    web-console (4.0.1)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    wice_grid (3.6.2)
      activerecord (> 3.2)
      coffee-rails (> 3.2)
      kaminari (~> 0.16)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.2.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  font-awesome-sass (~> 4.3)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mysql2 (>= 0.4.4)
  puma (~> 4.1)
  rails (~> 6.0.1)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  tiny_tds
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)
  wice_grid

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

## Results

```
$ rails g wice_grid:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 32123
Could not find generator 'wice_grid:install'.
```

## Expected

Should generate `config/initializers/wice_grid_config.rb`

Comment: Probably, this answer will help to understand what was the cause of your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251853/12201472

Answer (score 1):

## Just found a solution:

1. spring stop
2. rails g wice_grid:install

## Result

```
$ rails g wice_grid:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 32550
create  config/initializers/wice_grid_config.rb
```

## Reference

https://qiita.com/NaokiIshimura/items/e01cb95d71ffa5811f63