# Can't install RSpec on Rails 5 - Could not find generator 'rspec:install'

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

My Gemfile has the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'

gem 'rails', '>= 5.0.0.rc2', '< 5.1'

... more gems

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.7'
  gem 'byebug'

end

group :test do
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.3'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.53', '>= 2.53.4'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'


end
```

When I run rails generate rspec install, I get

```
Expected string default value for '--helper'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--assets'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--decorator'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)
Could not find generator 'rspec:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'pundit:install' or 'responders:install'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

rails generate --help shows no rspec install

```
Rspec:
  rspec:decorator
  rspec:policy
```

my gem list rspec shows..
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
rspec (3.5.0)
rspec-core (3.5.4)
rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
rspec-support (3.5.0)
```

I can't seem to install rspec. Is there something I need to do differently?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426406/could-not-find-generator-rspecinstall OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962048/rails-4-could-not-find-generator-rspecinstall ?

Comment: bundle install --with test

Comment: My gems were not installing in the test environment.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, too.

I solved it this way.

Try this command:

```
spring stop
```

then run again:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

---

【MyError】

Running via Spring preloader in process 23226

Expected boolean default value for '--markerb'; got :erb (string)

Could not find generator 'rspec:install'. Maybe you meant 'responders:install', 'devise:install' or 'channel'

Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

Comment: I was missing some gems so I did bundle update and ran  bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test